# Working with TextField() on Django

Tags: python, django

In this project I receive an input containing various info (i.e.: name, age, social number, DoB) in a single string.

In this case I'm using `TextField` on Django, and I'd like to separate each info and store them in the database. I already tried using the `split()` but it only works with strings, and I don't know how to `TextField` into string.

models.py

```
class InputData(models.Model):
    inputData = models.TextField()
    criado_em = models.DateTimeField('criado em', auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['criado_em']
        verbose_name = (u'inputData')
        verbose_name_plural = (u'inputData\'s')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.inputData
```

form.py

```
class CadastroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InputData
        #fields = ('inputData')
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

class Criar(CreateView):
    template_name = 'cadastro.html'
    model = InputData
    #fields = ('inputData')
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista')

class Lista(ListView):
    template_name = 'lista.html'
    model = InputData
    context_object = 'inputData'
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^cadastro/$', Criar.as_view(), name='cadastro'),
    url(r'^lista/$', Lista.as_view(), name = 'lista'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I'll receive the string (`inputData`) through a web form:

```
"2014-02-05 09:40:00",118726,13.23,28.78,233.1908
```

I'd like to store these infos (which are separated by commas) in different variables.

Comment: Your description makes no sense. A TextField  *is* a string.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your model, removing the `inputData` field and adding the "split" fields so that they are stored separately in the database:

```
class InputData(models.Model):
    # change, name, and insert parameters as appropriate for the data you are storing
    date_1 = models.DateTimeField(...)
    number_1 = models.IntegerField(...)
    float_1 = models.DecimalField(...)
    float_2 = models.DecimalField(...)
    float_3 = models.DecimalField(...)
    criado_em = models.DateTimeField('criado em', auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, you will need to run [model migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) to sync your database up. The exact commands and what you'll need to do varies based on the version of Django you're using, and how you setup your app, but hopefully it shouldn't be hard.

Now, if you don't mind having multiple fields in your webform for each of your pieces of data (and hopefully you don't, as this is much easier for a human to use than entering a comma-delimited string), this is all you'll need to do. Because you have `fields = "__all__"` specified in your view configuration, all the new fields will show up and can be entered. However, if you need to still accept the same string (perhaps it's being pasted from elsewhere) you'll need to do a *lot* more work.

First, you'll need to create a `forms.py` in your app and create a new form (note the use of the `forms` module):

```
class InputDataCreateForm(forms.Form):
    inputData = forms.TextField(...) # insert appropriate parameters
```

Then, in `views.py`, you'll need to import your new form and modify `Criar` as follows:

```
class Criar(CreateView):
    template_name = 'cadastro.html'
    model = InputData
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista')
    form_class = InputDataCreateForm

    # this will get called when the form is submitted and is valid
    def form_valid(self, form):
        inputData = form.cleaned_data['inputData'] # get the string
        if self.object is None:
            self.object = InputData()
        # insert all fields you are going to be extracting from the
        # input string here in the proper order:
        self.object.date_1, self.object.date_2, ... = inputData.split(',')
        self.object.save()
        return self.get_success_url()
```

However, I'd like to point out this is *extremely* prone to breaking. For example, what happens if I enter a string that splits into 6 items instead of 5 (or however many the app is expecting)? What if I enter a string that looks like `"not-a-date 30:61:61,numbers,5/2,hello,testing` (I forgot the second quote in the date on purpose)? You have to do manual validation on each of those things when you could just have people enter each field separately, and you would only have to change your model. Unless you really, *really* need to be able to have users enter a string in exactly that format, I wouldn't go that route.